# Graphing three database in one graph Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

How can I plot the graph

- Getting the data from those 3 sources
- Using only first letter and last digits of the first column to put it in the X-axis as in the Excel graph above
- How can I only show first column data by 20 digits difference ? aa010 aa030 aa050 ... etc

I have three different data from a source. Each one of them has 2 columns. Some of those 3 sources' first columns named the same but each one of them has different data corresponding to it in the second column.

I need to use python to plot those 3 data at one graph.

X-axis should be the combination of the first column of three data from the sources. - The data is in format of: aa001 - (up to sometimes aa400); ab001 - (up to sometimes ab400).

So, the X-axis should start with a aa001 and end with ab400. Since it would just overfill the x-axis and would make it impossible to look at it in a normal size, I want to just show aa020, aa040 ..... (using the number in the string, only show it after aa0(+20) or ab0(+20))

Y-axis should be just numbers from 0-10000 (may want to change if at least one of the data has max more than 10000.

I will add the sample graph I created using excel.

My sample data would be (Note: Data is not sorted by any column and I would prefer to sort it as stated above: aa001 ...... ab400):

Data1

Name Number

aa001 123

aa032 4211

ab400 1241

ab331 33

---

Data2

Name Number

aa002 1213

aa032 41

ab378 4231

ab331 63

aa163 999

---

Data3

Name Number

aa209 9876

ab132 5432

ab378 4124

aa031 754

aa378 44

ab344 1346

aa222 73

aa163 414

ab331 61

I searched up Matplotlib, found a sample example where it plots as I want (with dots for each x-y point) but does not apply to my question.

This is the similar code I found:

```
x = range(100)
y = range(100,200)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.scatter(x[:4], y[:4], s=10, c='b', marker="s", label='first')
ax1.scatter(x[40:],y[40:], s=10, c='r', marker="o", label='second')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');
plt.show()
```

Sample graph (instead of aa for X-axis-> bc; ab -> mc)

I expect to see a graph as follows, but skipping every 20 in the X-axis. (I want the first graph dotted (symbolled) as the second graph but second graph to use X-axis as the first graph, but with skipping 20 in the name

[First Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqD3e.png) ->- I want to use X-axis like this but without each data (only by 20 difference)

[Second graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QWu7.png) ->- I want to use symbols instead of lines like in this one

Please, let me know if I need to provide any other information or clarify/correct myself. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Data1Number ab310mc bc Xaxis (+45), although bb030 aa100 also.

Comment: I have updated how the data looks now. Also, could you please clarify your answer? I do not understand what do you mean to say? Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: The answer will be in the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708769/using-sorted-file-to-plot-x-axis-with-corresponding-y-values-from-the-original-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as following but the following code has still some errors. The final answer will be posted after receiving complete answer at The answer will be in the following link:
[Using sorted file to plot X-axis with corresponding Y-values from the original file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708769/using-sorted-file-to-plot-x-axis-with-corresponding-y-values-from-the-original-f)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

csv_file = []
with open('hostnum.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        csv_file.append(line)

us_csv_file = []
with open('unsorted.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file.append(line)
us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_list.index(x[1]))

plt.plot([int(item[1]) for item in csvfile], 'o-')
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csvfile)), [item[0] for item in csvfile])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I would like to see github documentation on this matter as well. Please gather it all as you did in your another question and post it in your github please