# Using sorted file to plot X-axis with corresponding Y-values from the original file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, matplotlib, graph

[Sample Data on GitHub](https://github.com/RusifE/Using-sorted-file-to-plot-X-axis-scatter-graph-with-corresponding-Y-values-from-the-original-file)

I have a csv file which has 2 columns. The first column is in the format of: `name001.a.a` and the second column is 4 digit number (ex: `0001`).

I have another file which has sorted first column of the file above.

The purpose in indexing the first column is because 1) I have many of these files that I will be plotting in a same graph in the future 2) I need them to be sorted.

The actual file (**us_csv_file**)which has both columns is in the format of following:

```
name002.a.a,0002
name001.a.a,0001
name005.a.a,0025
```

The sorted CSV file (**hostnum.csv**) -  I use to sort the first column is as follows (delimiter is a TAB):

```
"1    name001.a.a"
"2    name002.a.a"
"3    name005.a.a"
```

I have tried to search for any other ideas to work around it, or solve it, but could not find it. Anyone could help me with the code please?

My question is:

How can I use the sorted file to plot the X-axis with the label of strings (without the index numbers) but show the corresponding 4 digits number from the 1st file for Y-values?

The sample graph I created using excel would look like this:
[Graph that was created as a model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMS3b.png)

**------------------------------------------------------------**
**EDIT 1**------------------------------------------------------------

*** UPDATED:GRAPH I GET AFTER THE CODE BELOW ***
[After New Code -GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70q6t.png)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker as ticker
from textwrap import wrap
import numpy as np
import csv

csv_file = []
with open('hostnum.csv', 'r') as host:
    for line in host.readlines():
        line = line.replace('"', '')
        line = line.strip('\n')
        rank, value = line.split("  ")
        csv_file.append(value)

us_csv_file = []
with open('firsFile.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file.append(line)

us_csv_file1 = []
with open('secondFile.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file1.append(line)

us_csv_file2 = []
with open('thirdFile.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file2.append(line)        

us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[0]))
us_csv_file1.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[0]))
us_csv_file2.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[0]))


plt.title("\n".join(wrap("ery very very very long long long title title title that that that wrapped wrapped wrapped")))
plt.xlabel("Node Names", fontsize = 8)
plt.ylabel("Run Times", fontsize = 8)



plt.plot([int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file], 'o-')
plt.plot([int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file1], 'o-')
plt.plot([int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file2], 'o-')

#plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csv_file)), [item for item in csv_file])
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csv_file))[::100], csv_file[::100])
plt.savefig('./test.png') #saves a picture of the graph to the file

plt.show()
```

**------------------------------------------------------------**
**EDIT 2**------------------------------------------------------------

Changed the plot to scatter. But, values do not match to x-axis. Added a sample picture, but instead of numbers in the x-axis, there should be node names, as same as my sample picture above
Updated lines:

```
plt.scatter(range(len(us_csv_file)), [int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file], c='r')

#plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csv_file)), [item for item in csv_file])
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csv_file))[::1], csv_file[::1])
plt.savefig('./test.png')
```

***What I am trying to get with host names as X-axis***
[image: Scatter Graph Sample]

**------------------------------------------------------------**
**EDIT 3**------------------------------------------------------------

Changed the code at the end to clear the X-axis, but it is still not working. Additionally, graphed with 3 files I have and added different symbols for each.

***Updated Code***

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from textwrap import wrap
import csv

csv_file = []
with open('hostnum.csv', 'r') as host:
    for line in host.readlines():
        line = line.replace('"', '')
        line = line.strip('\n')
        rank, value = line.split("  ")
        csv_file.append(value)

us_csv_file = []
with open('firsFile.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file.append(line)

us_csv_file1 = []
with open('secondFile.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file1.append(line)

us_csv_file2 = []
with open('thirdFile.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file2.append(line)


us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[0]))
us_csv_file1.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[0]))
us_csv_file2.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[0]))


plt.scatter(range(len(us_csv_file)), [int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file], c='r', marker='+', label="First")
plt.scatter(range(len(us_csv_file1)), [int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file1], c='b', marker=(5,2), label="Second")
plt.scatter(range(len(us_csv_file2)), [int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file2], c='g', marker=(5,1), label="Third")

plt.legend(loc='upper right') #where to indicate the labels of the signs
plt.grid(True) #Created grid for x-y axises

plt.title("\n".join(wrap("long long long long long long tittle ttitle ttitle that that fixed fixed ")))
plt.xlabel("Node Names", fontsize = 8)
plt.ylabel("Run Times", fontsize = 8)

#plt.xticks(np.arange(0,len(csv_file),1000)[::2], csv_file[::2])
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csv_file))[::2], csv_file[::2])
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,11000,1000))

plt.show()
```

***Graph with X-axis labels unclear (as it shows it by Gridlines as well)***
[image: Graph with X-axis labels unclear with Gridlines]

*** FINAL GRAPH***
[image: Final Graph]

Comment: `csvfile.sort` does not exist so calling it will raise an error. The only possible fix is not calling it.

Comment: Hi @Goyo, without calling it, how can i use the "hostnum.csv" - sorted file to sort the "unsorted.csv" file? I updated the code above in my second edit. I should not use csv_list it says. How can I fix it so it still sorts one CSV using the other sorted CSV fileThanks for the help

Comment: @Goyo, Could you please explain what I should do besides removing csvfile.sort? That's the main thing I need and removing it does not help.

Comment: Maybe start by forgetting about `hostnum.csv`, I don't think you need it at all. Then stop thinking about sorting files. You only want the files to read the data into some data structure, then you manipulate the data structure, not the file. But I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Goyo, the reason I need to sort is because I will have 4 different files. 1 of them will have the indexed names - sorted names. Others will have only unsorted/un-indexed names and corresponding numbers to it. Those 3 files use same names maybe once or more but with different corresponding numbers. Final purpose is to compare those 3 files data (by their numbers) but have the names on the x-axis. To do that, I need them all sorted so when I would only need to put all the Names in the X-axis and corresponding numbers from 3 different files using different colors

Comment: Again, you do not sort files, you do not plot files. You read the data from the file, then sort the data, do whatever manipulations you need on the data, then plot the data.

Comment: Hello @Goyo , I beleive you downgraded the both questions I posted. May I know why and what I can do in order you to vote positive in the questions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: The sorting is probably not the most efficient method, but something to start with**

Load the CSV file with [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and iterate it into a list

Load the sorted XML file into another list as well *(Note: you can probably use `csv.reader()` again and set the delimiter to tab to keep it simple)*

The syntax for loading a CSV file is as follows:

```py
import csv
csv_file = []
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        csv_file.append(line)
```

See the [`csv.reader()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) for more info and using delimiters. Just to be safe, remember to change the variable name of the file and reader when opening different files.

However, for your `hostnum.csv`, `csv` won't work, so you can write a parser by hand. I've done it for you:

```py
csv_file = []
with open('/Users/dash/Documents/hostnum.csv', 'r') as host:
    for line in host.readlines():
        line = line.replace('"', '')
        line = line.strip('\n')
        rank, value = line.split("    ")
        csv_file.append(value)
```

Sort the list by each element's position in the xml list:

`us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[0]))`

This works by using a lambda (anonymous function) to take the string in the CSV file and look up its row number in the sorted XML file. The lambda returns a number, which sort then uses to set the new position the element in the list.

See [the python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) for a basic tutorial on sorting.

For plotting, use[`matplotlib.pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) and set the xticks with [`matplotlib.pyplot.xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

Ex:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot([int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file], 'o-')
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csv_file)), [item for item in csv_file])

plt.show()
```

[image: The end result]

Hope this helps!

EDIT: use `csv_file` in the `lambda`

EDIT2: Here's the full code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

csv_file = []
with open('hostnum.csv', 'r') as host:
    for line in host.readlines():
        line = line.replace('"', '')
        line = line.strip('\n')
        rank, value = line.split("    ")
        csv_file.append(value)

us_csv_file = []
with open('us_csv_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file.append(line)

us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[0]))

plt.plot([int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file], 'o-')
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csv_file)), [item for item in csv_file])

plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT (Again)**
After thinking about it, I think the best way would be to create a dict for each node with all the values stored in it.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from textwrap import wrap
import csv

#Opens the sorted hostnum.csv file and reads it; replaces the quotation marks.
csv_file = []
with open('hostnum.csv', 'r') as host:
    for line in host.readlines():
        line = line.replace('"', '')
        line = line.strip('\n')
        rank, value = line.split("  ")
        csv_file.append(value)

#Opens the file and reads it
us_csv_file = []
with open('fileFirst.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file.append(line)

us_csv_file1 = []
with open('fileSecond.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file1.append(line)

us_csv_file2 = []
with open('fileThird.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file2.append(line)


runs = []

file_0 = {}
file_1 = {}
file_2 = {}

for result in us_csv_file:
    node_name = result[0]
    node_value = result[1]

    if file_0.get(node_name):   # If the node exists in the list
        file_0[node_name].append(node_value)
    else:
        file_0[node_name] = [node_value]

runs.append(file_0)

for result in us_csv_file1:
    node_name = result[0]
    node_value = result[1]

    if file_1.get(node_name):   # If the node exists in the list
        file_1[node_name].append(node_value)
    else:
        file_1[node_name] = [node_value]

runs.append(file_1)

for result in us_csv_file2:
    node_name = result[0]
    node_value = result[1]

    if file_2.get(node_name):   # If the node exists in the list
        file_2[node_name].append(node_value)
    else:
        file_2[node_name] = [node_value]

runs.append(file_2)


# all_plots = [[[], []],[[], []],[[], []]]

all_plots = [] # Make an array of 3 arrays, each with a pair of arrays inside
# Each pair holds the x and y coordinates of the datapoints

for x in range(3):
    all_plots.append([[],[]])


for run_number, run_group in enumerate(runs):

    for key, values in run_group.items():
        sorted_position = csv_file.index(key)
        for item in values:
            all_plots[run_number][0].append(sorted_position)
            all_plots[run_number][1].append(int(item))

#indicates the label names at the given spot
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

#Creates grid for x-y axises
plt.grid(True)

#Creates wrapped title for the graph
plt.title("\n".join(wrap("longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongTITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLE")),size = 9.5)

#x-y labels for the graph
plt.xlabel("Node Names", fontsize = 8)
plt.ylabel("Run Times", fontsize = 8)

#ticks - x and y axisses' data format.

plt.scatter(all_plots[0][0], all_plots[0][1], c='b', marker='+', label="First")
plt.scatter(all_plots[1][0], all_plots[1][1], c='g', marker=(5,2), label="Second")
plt.scatter(all_plots[2][0], all_plots[2][1], c='r', marker=(5,1), label="Third")


plt.xticks(range(len(csv_file))[::25], [item for item in csv_file][::25], rotation=90, size=8)


plt.yticks(np.arange(0,11000,1000), size=8)

#Saves a PNG file of the current graph to the folder and updates it every time
plt.savefig('./test.png', bbox_inches='tight')

# Not to cut-off bottom labels(manually) - enlarges bottom
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.23)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195610/discussion-on-answer-by-dash-using-sorted-file-to-plot-x-axis-with-corresponding).