# How to plot multiple graphs in one using 3 different files and another file to sort them?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, sorting

I have 2 CSV files. One of them has the sorted data and another unsorted. Example data is as shown below.

I am trying to do is to take the unsorted data and sort it according to index numbers from the sorted data. Ex: in the sorted data, I have index number "1" corresponds to "name001.a.a". So, since it iss index number = "1", In the unsorted file, I want "name 001.a.a,0001" to be the first in the list. The number after the comma in unsorted file is 4 digit number which does not play a role in sorting but is attached to the names.

One more sample would be: index "2" is for "name002.a.a", so after sorting, new file would have "name002.a.a,0002" as a second item in the list

***unsorted.csv:***

```
name002.a.a,0002
name001.a.a,0001
name005.a.a,0025
```

***hostnum.csv (sorted):***

```
"1    name001.a.a"
"2    name002.a.a"
"3    name005.a.a"
```

I need help to figure out where I have coded wrong and if possible, need help with completing it.

**EDIT- CODE:**
After changing the name csv_list to csv_file, I am receiving the following error

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

csv_file = []
with open('hostnum.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        csv_file.append(line)

us_csv_file = []
with open('unsorted.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file.append(line)
us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[1]))

plt.plot([int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file], 'o-')
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csvfile)), [item[0] for item in csvfile])

plt.show()
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/..../TEST_ALL.py", line 16, in <module>
    us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[1]))
  File "C:/..../TEST_ALL.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[1]))
ValueError: '0002' is not in list
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sorted file to plot X-axis with corresponding Y-values from the original file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708769/using-sorted-file-to-plot-x-axis-with-corresponding-y-values-from-the-original-f)

Comment: Hello @Goyo,  yes, that's my post as well. I just wanted more specified answer. Sorry about possibly duplicating it.

Comment: Hello @Goyo , I beleive you downgraded the both questions I posted. May I know why and what I can do in order you to vote positive in the questions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you haven't defined `csv_list` in your code. Looking quickly through your code, I'd guess changing `us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_list.index(x[1]))` to `us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file.index(x[1]))` (i.e. using the correct variable name, which is `csv_file` and not `csv_list`), might just solve the problem.

---

Here's a new attempt. This one tries to extract the numbers from the second column from hostnum.csv and puts them onto a separate list, which it then uses to sort the items. When I run this code, I get `ValueError: '025' is not in list` but I assume that's because you haven't given us the entire files and there is indeed no such line that would contain `name025.a.a` in the snippet of hostnum.csv you gave us, I also added a `[1:]` to the sorting statement.

If this doesn't work, try removing that `[1:]` and changing `csv_file_numbers.append(csv_file[-1][1][4:].split('.')[0])` to `csv_file_numbers.append(csv_file[-1][1][4:].split('.')[0].zfill(4))`. `string.zfill(4)` will add zeros to the beginning of a string so long that its length is at least 4.

Because your sorted file contains one more zero than the unsorted file, I also changed

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

csv_file = []
csv_file_numbers = []

##with open('hostnum.csv', 'r') as f:
##    csvreader = csv.reader(f, dialect="excel-tab")
##    for line in csvreader:
##        csv_file.append(line)
##        csv_file_numbers.append(line[-1][4:].split('.')[0])

with open('hostnum.csv', 'r') as f:
    sorted_raw = f.read()

for line in sorted_raw.splitlines():
    csv_file.append(line.split('\t'))
    csv_file_numbers.append(csv_file[-1][1][4:].split('.')[0])

us_csv_file = []
with open('unsorted.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file.append(line)
us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file_numbers.index(x[1][1:]))

plt.plot([int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file], 'o-')
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csvfile)), [item[0] for item in csvfile])

plt.show()
```

---

This one worked on my computer:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

csv_file = []
csv_file_dict = {}

##with open('hostnum.csv', 'r') as f:
##    csvreader = csv.reader(f, dialect="excel-tab")
##    for line in csvreader:
##        csv_file.append(line)
##        csv_file_numbers.append(line[-1][4:].split('.')[0])

with open('hostnum.csv', 'r') as f:
    sorted_raw = f.read()

for line in sorted_raw.splitlines():
    csv_file.append(line.split('\t'))
    csv_file_dict[csv_file[-1][-1][:-1]] = int(csv_file[-1][0][1:])

us_csv_file = []
with open('unsorted.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
        us_csv_file.append(line)
us_csv_file.sort(key=lambda x: csv_file_dict[x[0]])

plt.plot([int(item[1]) for item in us_csv_file], 'o-')
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csv_file)), [item[0] for item in csv_file])

plt.show()
```

So now I created a dict which stores the index values as values and the names of each cell that is found in both files as keys. I also removed the quotations manually, as for some reason, `csv.reader` didn't seem to do it correctly, at least it didn't handle the tabs in the desired way. As I wrote in one of my comments, I don't know why for sure, I'd guess it's because the quotations are not closed within the cells in the file. Anyway, I decided to split each line manually with `string.split('\t').`

Also, you had missed the underscore in the variable name `csv_file` from a couple of places at the end, so I added them.

Comment: Hello @hilssu,

After changing it, I am getting a ValueError. Could you please check the new EDIT part of the question? What should i do to fix this ValueError?

Comment: One problem is that your hostnum.csv file is not comma separated. Is it tab-separated or does it use four spaces as a separator? When I copy and paste the content of hostnum.csv to Notepad, the resulting file will be separated with four spaces, but it could just be a StackOverflow quirk. I'll try again once you answer that question of mine.

Comment: Hello @hilssu, it is a tab separated within quotation marks. Indeed and if it is the issue, I could change the tab separation to a comma, but would prefer not to. Also, thank you for your time and help!

Comment: For some reason, csvreader = csv.reader(f, dialect="excel-tab") did not work in reading the tab separated file, it left some tabs in the cells. I don't know why, I'm not a super-experienced programmer either.

Comment: Hello @hilssu. I believe  I made the sample data confusing. What I am trying to do is to take the unsorted data and sort it according to index numbers from the sorted data. Ex: in the sorted data, I have index number "1"  corresponds to "name001.a.a". So, since it iss index number = "1", In the unsorted file, I want "name 001.a.a,0001" to be the first in the list. The number after the comma in unsorted file is 4 digit number which does not play a role in sorting but is attached to the names.

Comment: One more sample would be: index "2" is for "name002.a.a", so after sorting, new file would have "name002.a.a,0002" as a second item in the list

Comment: Making the changes as you said above in your edit, gave me the error you had about 025 which should be there. But changing it again with your another suggestion, I get the following error: "    plt.xticks(np.arange(len(csvfile)), [item[0] for item in csvfile])
NameError: name 'csvfile' is not defined"

Comment: OK, I finally understood your question correctly. The last code above worked on me, when the file was latin-1-encoded. The NameError comes because the variable name you defined is csv_file and you're trying to call it using the name csvfile, which is wrong.

Comment: Hello @hilssu, due to time difference I could not check your reply quickly. Thanks for the new update.  I run into new error. Is it because I need to convert the data to latin-1-encoded? The error is: ```"line 19, in <module>
    csv_file_dict[csv_file[-1][-1][:-1]] = int(csv_file[-1][0][1:])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''```" Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't understand your last comment, but the error (invalid literal for int() with base 10: '') seems to mean that the hostnum.csv file contains a line that starts with just a quotation mark (or any character for that matter) not followed by a number. For example, if I change the first line from "1 name001.a.a" to " name001.a.a", I would get the same error. Also, an error like that could occur if the quotation mark was missing from some line in hostnum.csv.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Yes, there was a mistake in the hostnum since I deleted the quotation marks. But now it works. Only question is left is how can I print the names instead of  ```"1``` then ```"2``` in the X-axis. But I want the names to be shown skipping every 20 of the,. Like ```name001.a.a```  then ```name021.a.a``` . Thanks again for the help!

Comment: For that you could build a list of correct labels (most of them which would be empty strings), and feed that as the second argument to plt.xticks, like so: https://pastebin.com/xGmGLTSh (Might not be the most efficient way, but works)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.